# .velocity is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, velocity

Head :

```
<!-- Velocity -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>

<!--  React  -->
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/2.7.0/ReactRouter.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/superagent/2.2.0/superagent.js"></script>
```

Velocity is included by `let velocity = window.Velocity`

If i try to `console.log(velocity)` it shows a function,if i console log `document.getElementById("menu)` it shows an element,however when i try to run `document.getElementById("menu).velocity("slideDown", { duration: 1500 });`after my component is rendered console says

> Uncaught TypeError: dbyId(...).velocity is not a function

What could be the reason for this happening?I am using babel transformer with php back-end,no requires or imports are happening.

Comment: window does not have any function by `velocity`

Comment: `window.velocity !== element.velocity` The fact that that function exists on `window` doesn't mean it does on the element.

Comment: if you are talking about window.Velocity it does,if i console log it it shows a function and if I click on it in chrome dev tools it redirects to velocity.min.js @ user2181397

Comment: `window.Velocity !== window.velocity`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Cerbrus if you read what i said, you could clearly see that importing of velocity is fine.

Comment: @August: If the comments you're talking about `window.Velocity`, in your question about `window.velocity` and `getElementById(...).velocity`. Those are 3 completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use jQuery you need to use

```
Velocity(document.getElementById("menu"), { opacity: 0.5 });
```

since velocity don't add stuff to element prototype.

Comment: Yep,that was the issue.Thank you